# A problem when wrongly using Dot command in Mma

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
In[1]:= SameQ[Dot[1, 2], 1.2]
TrueQ[Dot[1, 2] == 1.2]

a = 1; b = 2;
SameQ[Dot[a, b], a.b]
TrueQ[Dot[a, b] == a.b]

Out[1]= False

Out[2]= False

Out[4]= True

Out[5]= True
```

I know this uses `Dot` command wrong. Anybody can give me a clear reson for the above different results?

thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`a.b` is interpreted as `Dot[a,b]` and then variables `a` and `b` are substituted, meaning `Dot[1,2]` and thus equality holds. This is not the same as `1.2` where the dot stands for the decimal separator and not for the inline operator of `Dot`.

Comment: Further information: If you want to use infix Dot with arguments like 1 and 2, you need to add some spaces: 1 . 2 === Dot[1, 2]

Comment: Thanks,Moylan. really really helpful and extensive!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

When you write `1.2`, Mma understands a number (aka 6/5), but if you write `{1, 1}.{2, 2} or a.b` Mma understands a [**scalar product**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), as usual in any book using vectors.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

It can be informative to view an expression under `Hold` and `FullForm`:

```
a = 1; b = 2;
SameQ[Dot[a, b], a.b]] //Hold //FullForm
```

```
    Hold[SameQ[Dot[a, b], Dot[a, b]]]
```

With this combination of commands, Mathematica parses but does not evaluate the expression (`Hold`), and then shows the long pseudo-internal form of the expression (`FullForm`).

In this case, you can see that the second term `a.b` is parsed as `Dot[a, b]` before any evaluation happens.

When `.` appears with numerals as in `1.2` it is interpreted specially as a decimal point.  This is similar to other numeric entry formats such as:  `1*^6` which is recognized directly as `1000000`:

```
1*^6 //Hold //FullForm
```

Compare trying to enter:

```
a = 1;

a*^6
```